# How to find which process the linux os running at a given moment?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, system-calls

So a OS multi-tasks and runs one process at a given moment (assuming it's a single core machine). Is there a way I can track/poll and find which process was running at what time and at what time it was put in the queue and retrieved back. Are there any system calls for this ?. Is there a way to achieve this without modifying the linux kernel's source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [lttng](http://www.lttng.org/), it definitely give a you a elaborate view of the system's task switch thing(and much more than that) with the lttng viewer. Lttng's kernel part has been merged to current Linux kernel, and you can use it if your kernel has enabled this feature. [Here](http://www.lttng.org/?q=node/8) is some screen shots for lttng.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this natively. AFAIK linux does not a keep a history track of this information.

Answer (score 0):

That's an illogical question. If you are querying the OS from a script/process then the active program is ... YOURS.

Though I guess if you want the history you could watch the `/proc` directory or the output from `ps`

Comment: It's not a illogical question. Perhaps it's not well formed/ put properly.

Comment: If you have a single core, whichever process is doing the monitoring is bound to discover that it, itself is running.